# Geometry has incorrect latitude-longitudes

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

- `SELECT ST_SRID(geom) AS s FROM zones GROUP BY s;`
  returns a single record: `4326`
- `SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'zones', 'geom');`
  returns `4326`
- `SELECT AsText(geom) FROM zones`
  returns geometry like:

`MULTIPOLYGON(((495468.88595 5464400.7263,495468.89 5464401.38005,...)))`

Shouldn't my geometry been standard lat-lngs? Something like:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.968967906831 49.31253667013,-122.970356138605 49.3125609975662...)))
```

I tried executing both of these queries, but neither worked:

`SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('zones','geom',4326);`
`UPDATE zones SET geom  = ST_Transform(geom);`

How can I transform the geometry into my desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the wrong id on load. Looks like you have a UTM projection.

Now need to transform to right geometry.

```
UPDATE zones
SET geom = st_transform( st_setsrid( geom, 31997 ), 4326 )
```